# How to fetch selected Radio buttons values from html page to views page in Django

Tags: django-forms

I am unable to fetch the selected radio buttons values from my html page..

```html
           <li> {{obj.question}} ?</li>
            <label class="container">{{obj.option1}}
             <input type="radio"  name="{{obj.qno}}" value="{{obj.option1}}">
                 <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
            <label class="container">{{obj.option2}}
              <input type="radio" name="{{obj.qno}}" value="{{obj.option2}}">
                 <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
            <label class="container">{{obj.option3}}
             <input type="radio" name="{{obj.qno}}" value="{{obj.option3}}">
              <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
            <label class="container">{{obj.option4}}
              <input type="radio" name="{{obj.qno}}" value="{{obj.option4}}">
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be possible, if inside the view.py page we are using a loop and passing radio buttons names(ex :- obj.qno) one by one and append the result to a list then we can get all the selected radio buttons values.

```
count = 0 
for i,obj in enumerate(objs):
   var = request.POST[obj.qno]   #  "obj.qno]" :- It is the name of 
                                     dynamically added radio buttons.
    if list_ans[i] == var:
        count += 1 # To count how many radio button values are matched.
```